# How to make a function like this in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, method-chaining, love2d

I wanna make a plugin where someone calls a function passes some info along with the call and makes a listenerfunction,
the function has to look like this:

```
database.execute(database.Update)
:data({username="Jhon"})
:response(function(responseString, responseTable)
    /// 
end)
```

I know how to make a basic function call like this `database.execute(_, _, _)` but have no idea how to make it multi-line operation like this

```
database.execute()
:_()
:_()
```

Comment: To make a chain, the methods involved must return the object.

Answer (score 6):

In order to make multiline calls you need to make table like the following example:

```
local mydatabase = { a=1 }
mydatabase.method1 = function( self, param )
    self.a = self.a + param
    return self
end
mydatabase.method2 = function( self, param )
    self.a = self.a * param
    return self
end
mydatabase.method3 = function( self, param )
    self.a = self.a - param
    return self
end

-- A chain of function calls
mydatabase:method1( 3 )
:method2( 2 )
:method3( 5 )

print( mydatabase.a ) -- Should return 3
```

so the method returns the table that contains the methods used to call them when returning